# Peer review on a Mediawiki wiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

Is it possible to somehow implement peer review on a Mediawiki wiki, like developers do with pull requests on GitHub? That way before an edit goes live, peers can review, discuss if necessary, ask for changes and/or approve.

Answer (score 1):

[ApprovedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Approved_Revs) and [FlaggedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs) are two extensions that do that.

For a more manual approach, you can copy the contents of the page to a new "pull request" page, edit and discuss there, and then "merge" with the `oldid`, `undo` and `undoafter` [parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Edit_and_submit) (they can point to different pages) which will basically try to do a 3-way merge (although if it fails, you get very little UI help for resolving the conflict).

A true GitHub-like workflow where the in-progress edit doesn't block other in-progress edits from proceeding is harder. [T113004](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T113004) is the issue tracker entry discussing how Wikipedia's revision system differs from Git's revision system and whether it could be made more similar, but it's not something to expect soon, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

Although simpler than GitHub, peer moderation is possible with [Extension:Moderation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Moderation). With this method any feedback to the editor will have to happen via their talk page and unapproved edits are lost from the page history.